# Form input height different depending on html doctype

Tags: css, html

I am new with html/css and i am facing a problem. According to my doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>` (first image) or `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` (second image), the height of the input of my form changes :

[image: input with html 5 doctype]

[image: input with html 4.01 doctype]

My question is why is there this difference ? And how could I have the second image style while using `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Here is the code of the form :

```
<form class="contact_form ajout-membre-form" action="prive2.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" class="login" placeholder="Identifiant" name="login" required=""> <label><img src="images2/contact/contact.png" alt=""></label></li>

                <li><input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" name="password" required=""> <label><img src="images2/prive/password.png" alt=""></label></li>
            </ul><input type="submit" class="next" value="Connexion">

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why is there this difference ? And how could I have the second image style while using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Can you post the input HTML please?

Comment: Yes, i've just added it in the question

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the issue. CSS code is missing, and the issue is how browsers implement CSS in different modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different [doctype definitions](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

which triggers HTML5 standards (which is not technically a standard yet, so it just triggers standards mode in most modern browsers)

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

which triggers HTML4 Transitional, or [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

The different modes have different rendering, as you are observing. Quirks mode is used to maintain backward compatibility with older browsers that don't abide by standards.

Specifically what you are seeing is the [difference in the way the two modes handle the box model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416094/how-do-i-make-standards-mode-work-as-well-as-quirks-mode#answer-416318). So, to fix it in HTML5/Standards mode, you can just remove padding from your `input` elements.